# Can't search by column name in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

So I've tried many things but I can't search by column names on my entire database(mysql) with PhpStorm.

Is this feature available? If so how do I do it? If not, is there any plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better way in my use cases:

- Select your database tables 'directory'. Hit 'Numpad *' (Fully Expand Tree Node) to expand the tree.
- Hit 'ctrl + f' to search column and table names in the folder.

It is way better than @Ástþór answer as it does not search css tags and other things.

Comment: I actually upvoted you. And did not cancel it as you answer was useful to me for a long time. However I did change the accepted answer to mine as it is better for my use case.

Comment: Ah, that's explains it. Sorry for that

Answer (score 3):

Try "Search everywhere" (shift+shift) or Navigate > Symbol (ctrl+alt+shift+N).